# Outside shadow of a cell in a collection view not showing up swift ios

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add shadow to the cell but it is not showing up
I followed [this tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-add-a-shadow-to-a-uiview)

```
    cell?.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    cell?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    cell?.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    cell?.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
    cell?.layer.shadowRadius = 10
    cell?.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: cell!.bounds).cgPath
    cell?.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    cell?.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
```

Comment: maybe your cell's bounds are not valid at the moment you set shadow. please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075673/shadow-layer-not-resizing-when-uiview-frame-changed

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `shadowOffset` to 0, the shadow will appear right behind the view and you will see the only the radius of it. Another thing is you must set **`layer.masksToBounds`** to **false** so that the radius of the shadow does not get clipped from the view's bounds.